# How to make UIPickerView with 3 visible rows?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

How to make uipickerview with only 3 visible rows? Like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not very sure with the localization, You need to set the appropriate dateMode to the `UIDatePicker` `[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];`

Comment: No... I mean how to make 3 visible ROWS, not columns..

Comment: Rows! Usially uipickerview has 5 visible rows. But this example has only 3... How they do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add UIDatePicker Programmatically to display three rows. Adjust the picker size according to your need.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 160, 320, 160);
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! In this case I can set minimum height for pickerview - 162. And interface builder makes the size only 216...
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I cant. My reputation is 3 only.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that most of the responses mentioned either **UIDatePicker** or the number of **Components**, neither of which seem right since the question specifically asks about **UIPickerView** and the number of **Rows Visible**.

I found a solution by implementing:

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return (80.0);
}
```

This allows you to make the height of the row larger (or smaller) so that fewer (or more) rows appear in the control, although the vertical size of the control is the same.

I do believe that the size of the control can be changed to avoid all the excess spacing, but I haven't addressed that issue yet.

---

Row Height 25.0

[image: row height 25.0]

---

Row Height 80.0

[image: row height 80.0]

Comment: thanks for making it clear there is no easy way to set desired size to pickerView. Indeed, datePicker is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @GRW's answer. So, you cant set arbitrary height to a picker view; but you Can: change row height to have 3 visible rows; AND apply affine transform to scale down the whole picker view.

To maintain the aspect ratio:

- you must scale not only *y*, but *x* too with the same scale factor;
- divide -pickerView:widthForComponent: by the scale factor;
- divide -pickerView:rowHeightForComponent: by the scale factor;
- if you have labels / text in components' rows, the font size must by divided by the factor as well.

> ```
> // consider
> CGFloat _scaleFactor = 0.5;
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>     self.pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor);
> }
>
> - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
> {
>     return desiredHeight / _scaleFactor;
> }
>
> - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component;
> {
>     return desiredWidth / _scaleFactor;
> }
>
> - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
> {
>     return desiredHeight / _scaleFactor;
> }
>
> - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
>           forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
> {
>     UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
>     if (!label) {
>         label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
>         CGFloat desiredFontSize;
>         label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(desiredFontSize / _scaleFactor)];
>     }
>
>     // set text from data source
>     return label;
> }
> ```

The difference versus blocking out not-to-be-visible rows is quite subtle; however, in my opinion the scaled picker on the right looks way more natural... In fact, that makes a big difference.

[image]

*(scale factor used is 0.5)*

Answer (score 0):

Try following code -

```
#pragma mark - picker datasource methods
    -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return 3;
    }

    #pragma mark - picker delegate
    -(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return [YourArray objectAtIndex:row];//your array that contains data

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
//Method to define how many columns/dials to show
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}


// Method to define the numberOfRows in a component using the array.
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent :(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    if (component==0)
    {
        return [arrFirst count];
    }
    else if (component==1)
    {
        return [arrSecond count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [arrThird count];
    }

}


// Method to show the title of row for a component.
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (component) 
    {
        case 0:
            return [arrFirst objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [arrSecond objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [arrThird objectAtIndex:row];
            break;    
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Thanks, Do let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: No... Note that usually pickerView has 5 visible ROWS!!! And this example has only 3... How they do that?

Comment: I have found that you can achieve a change in the height of the view by taking complete control and passing a desired frame size at creation time, e.g:

you need to set Height programmatically like : ObjPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 120.0)];